# Importing a function from another python file caused the entire python file to be executed instead of just the function called

Tags: python-3.x, function

I am trying to access just a function funtionc1() of python_file1.py from python_file2.py. When I run python_file2.py it runs the entire code of python_file1.py instead of just executing the function from python_file1.py.

Code:

### Python_file1.py

```py
print("This is Python_file1.py")

def function1():
    print("This is a function written inside Python_file1.py")
```

### Python_file2.py

```py
import Python_file1

from Python_file1 import function1

print("This is Python_file2.py")

Python_file1.function1()
```

Output from Python_file2.py=

This is Python_file1.py <<<<<<<<<<< I should not be seeing this

This is Python_file2.py

This is a function written inside Python_file1.py

However, I only want the function function1 from python_file1 to be run like this -
This is Python_file2.py

This is a function written inside Python_file1.py

What am I missing here? Pease advise.

Comment: That's what `import` *does* - it executes the imported file in its entirety, as that is the one and only way that the items defined in it can come into existence.  Importing a single item doesn't change anything, as Python has no way of knowing what portions of the file are (perhaps indirectly) referenced by that item.

Answer (score 2):

Remove the print statement, then. Importing will run the whole module...

And you have an extra import that does nothing

### Python_file1.py

```
def function1():
 print("This is a function written inside Python_file1.py")
```

### Python_file2.py

```
import Python_file1

print("This is Python_file2.py")

Python_file1.function1()
```

Output from Python_file2.py=

```
This is Python_file2.py

This is a function written inside Python_file1.py
```

Or keep the print statement, and then you can use this instead, not in addition to

```
from Python_file1 import function1
function1()  # just call like this
```

Comment: I do not want to modify/remove anything in python_file1 but just want to make use of the function that is defined in python_file1. So if I use the code you suggested, in the end, would still return all the contents of python_file1

Comment: You're going to have to modify something... What is stopping you from doing that?

Answer (score 0):

You can try the below hack to achieve the required result without changing the contents in `Python_file1.py`.

### In Python_file2.py:

```py
import os
import sys

# This is redirect the standard output
out = sys.stdout
null = open(os.devnull, 'w')
sys.stdout = null

from Python_file1 import function1

# Enable standard output
sys.stdout = out

print("This is Python_file2.py")
function1()
```

### Output:

```
This is Python_file2.py
This is a function written inside Python_file1.py
```